# Kotlin inferred type mismatch Error on my custom class datatype

Tags: android, kotlin

Basically i am new in kotlin, and i am getting "inferred type mismatch Error" when i update the version code and version name on this line.

`private lateinit var selectedPlan: SubscriptionItem`

`selectedPlan = params!!.getParcelable("selectedPlan")`

````
            selectedPlan = params!!.getParcelable("selectedPlan")!!
            when (selectedPlan.getPlanType()) {
                PlanType.STANDARD -> inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.layout_package_standard,
                    container,
                    false
                )
                PlanType.PREMIUM -> inflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.layout_package_premium,
                    container,
                    false
                )
                PlanType.BASIC -> inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_package_basic, container, false)
                else -> {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Unknown plan type", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_package_basic, container, false)
                }
            }
        } else {
            inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_package_basic, container, false)
        }```
````

Comment: Is your `PlanType` class parcelable or not ?

Answer (score 0):

the error is that your variable is not nullable and "getParcelable" return a nullable object

this should work:

```
selectedPlan = params!!.getParcelable("selectedPlan")!!
```

but is safer if you add a default value

```
selectedPlan = params?.getParcelable("selectedPlan") ?: PlanType.BASIC
```

Comment: When i am using this, its not working properly according to the flow.

Comment: how its not working? what is your use case? show more code

Comment: what is the issue?